# Ember-cli destDir doesn't work with app.import

Tags: ember-cli, broccolijs

When using ember cli I try do this but the file is not copied to dist:

```
app.import('bower_components/bootstrap/dist/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.eot', {
  destDir: 'fonts'
});
```

So when running the ember server I get:

```
version: 0.1.15
Could not find watchman, falling back to NodeWatcher for file system events
Build failed.
Path or pattern "glyphicons-halflings-regular.eot" did not match any files
Error: Path or pattern "glyphicons-halflings-regular.eot" did not match any files
```

what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Kindly double check wether you have your glyphicons-halflings-regular.eot is present under your bower_components folder.

If that didnt help updating your ember-cli and bootstrap to the latest version might help

```
npm update ember-cli
bower update bootstrap
```